# Ruby Regexp matches the data from the previous xml tag

Tags: ruby, regex, xml

My log file is like this,

```
2015-04-10 19:10:39,688 INFO  [abc] Reqt [283183]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>..<Name>EVENT_1</Name>..</Data>

2015-04-10 19:10:39,688 INFO  [abc] Req [283184]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>..<Name>MY_EVENT</Name>..</Data>
```

Regex what i have written is,

```
pFile    = File.read("C:/logs/pdata.log")
Regex = /<Data>(.*?)MY_EVENT(.*?)<\/Data>/m
pData    = pFile.match(Regex).to_s
```

"MY_EVENT" might come in the first xml tag or second xml tag or even at last based on the scenario. 
If it comes in first tag, regex works fine and if it comes in second tag, it matches from the first  and my output is like,

```
<Data>..<Name>EVENT_1</Name>..</Data>
2015-04-10 19:10:39,688 INFO  [abc] Req [283184]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>..<Name>MY_EVENT</Name>..</Data>
```

I need to extract only one xml tag which has MY_EVENT. 
Please help me out on this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
pData.match(/<Data>((?!<Data>).)*?MY_EVENT((?!<Data>).)*?<\/Data>/m)
```

I assume that all `<Data>` elements never contain another `<Data>` as its child element.